# Error in downloading multiple pdf files from websites using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pdf

I am reading a column from excel file using `pandas.read_excel`. This column has values which are direct links to the pdf document. I am converting this column to a `numpy_ndarray` and subsequently to python list using `list(df.flatten())`

I have went through multiple libraries like dload, wget,requests using which I tried to download the pdf links and tried to save it to a folder of my choice. However, I have had no luck so far.

Here is my code for the same

```
import dload
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_excel('examples.xlsx')
df1 = df['Source_URL'].to_numpy()
list_urls = list(df1.flatten())
pdfs = dload.save_multi(list_urls, dir='F:/technophile/proj/PDFs/', max_threads=8, tsleep=1)
print(pdfs)
print('saved!')
```

this is my list output:

```
['https://sustainabilityreport.abb.com/2020/servicepages/downloads/files/sustainability-performance-2020-abb-csr20.pdf', nan, 'https://sustainabilityreport.abb.com/2020/servicepages/downl
oads/files/sustainability-performance-2020-abb-csr20.pdf', 'https://sustainabilityreport.abb.com/2020/servicepages/downloads/files/sustainability-performance-2020-abb-csr20.pdf', 'https:/
/www.basf.com/global/documents/en/investor-relations/sustainable-investments/sustainability-ratings-and-rankings/BASF-SE_CDP_Climate_Change_Questionnaire_2021.pdf', nan, 'https://www.basf
.com/global/documents/en/investor-relations/sustainable-investments/sustainability-ratings-and-rankings/BASF-SE_CDP_Climate_Change_Questionnaire_2021.pdf', 'https://www.basf.com/global/do
cuments/en/investor-relations/sustainable-investments/sustainability-ratings-and-rankings/BASF-SE_CDP_Climate_Change_Questionnaire_2021.pdf', 'https://www.campbellcsr.com/_pdfs/Campbell_2
020_Water_and_GHG_Emissions_Limited_Assurance_Letter.pdf', nan, 'https://www.campbellcsr.com/_pdfs/Campbell_2020_Water_and_GHG_Emissions_Limited_Assurance_Letter.pdf', nan, 'https://www.m
ondelezinternational.com/-/media/Mondelez/Snacking-Made-Right/Impact-Reporting/Measuring-Our-Progress/Additional-Resources-2/CDPClimate2020.pdf', nan, 'https://www.mondelezinternational.c
om/-/media/Mondelez/Snacking-Made-Right/Impact-Reporting/Measuring-Our-Progress/Additional-Resources-2/CDPClimate2020.pdf', 'https://www.mondelezinternational.com/-/media/Mondelez/Snackin
g-Made-Right/Impact-Reporting/Measuring-Our-Progress/Additional-Resources-2/CDPClimate2020.pdf']
```

and this is my complete error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\technophile\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\dload\__init__.py", line 184, in save_multi
    fn = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
  File "C:\technophile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 372, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\technophile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 124, in _coerce_args
    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
  File "C:\technophile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 108, in _decode_args
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
  File "C:\technophile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 108, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'decode'
None
False
saved!
```

how do ensure that the pdfs from the given lists are saved at my destined folder without errors? Please help.

Comment: @KJ thanks for your prompt response, I am using windows to code hence I guess I would not be able to run this command. Is there any different approach to my solution?

Comment: it says No url specified. Also, I would like to add that the list of urls would be going over 6k. So is using curl in this scenario here useful? @KJ

Comment: @KJ I just noticed your piece of code, so you might have downloaded the pdf hence I could see your  c:\users\sustainblity... mine happens to be link, I have to download it from the link and then save it to my desktop.

Comment: @KJ this is what I got. >curl -o 'https://www.basf.com/global/documents/en/investor-relations/sustainable-investments/sustainability-ratings-and-ranki
ngs/BASF-SE_CDP_Climate_Change_Questionnaire_2021.pdf'
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information even if remove the quotes I get the same

Comment: Understood finally. I got this  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  739k  100  739k    0     0   369k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  273k

Comment: @KJ do you mean building a list in python with curl -o ? because I have created a list with urls except curl -o